# Convert json string from one type to another with .net core c#

Tags: c#, json

I am struggling to convert below input json to output json as this is what is the required format to call
hubspot api to submit a form. I am writing this using .net core within Azure function.

Input Json

```
{
    "Email":"myemail@test.com",
    "Phone":"12345678",
    "Address":"address 1"
}
```

Output json

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "Email",
      "value": "myemail@test.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Phone",
      "value": "12345678"
    },
    {
      "name": "Address",
      "value": "address 1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I converted the input json to dictionary using

```
IDictionary<string, string> dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, string>>(inputJson);
```

but that gives me key value pair instead of name value pair.

I would like the output as detailed above.

Any help/example code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: deserialize it to a dictionary, convert that to a list<keyvaluepair<,>>, serialize that.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own "NameValuePair" class/struct if you don't want "Key" as the field name:

```
public class FieldContainer
{
    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public IEnumerable<NameValuePair> Fields { get; set; }
}

public struct NameValuePair
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    
    public NameValuePair(string name, string value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

And then do like you've already done, but converting the `KeyValuePair`s into your own struct:

```
var inJson = @"{
    ""Email"":""myemail@test.com"",
    ""Phone"":""12345678"",
    ""Address"":""address 1""
}";

var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(inJson);
var container = new FieldContainer
{
    Fields = dict.Select(pair => new NameValuePair(pair.Key, pair.Value))
};

var outJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(container);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/arIzuF) for a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this would be to take the json and convert it to Dictionary<string, string>. Loop over each KeyValuePair and create a list of Fields using LINQ. Once you have the List of fields, create your RootObject.

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}
public class Field
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

// Create a dictionary
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonStr);

// Create a list of Fields
List<Field> fields = dict.Select(x => new Field() { Name = x.Key, Value = x.Value }).ToList();

// Create the final Object.
RootObject rootObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new RootObject() { Fields = fields });
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution, using `JObject.Parse()` to parse the original JSON, then iterate its Properties to create an array of JObjects with different names and values.
The resulting `IEnumerable<JObject>` is then converted to a JArray, used to create the final `fields` object.

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

var newObjects = jObj.Properties().Select(p => new JObject {
    new JProperty("name", p.Name),
    new JProperty("value", p.Value)});

var fields = new JObject() {
    { "fields",  JArray.FromObject(newObjects)}
};

Console.WriteLine(fields);
```